# Is it possible to infer TYPES of props, based on component passed into a higher order component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For example I have a simple component like this:

```
interface HomeProps {
  date: number;
  greeting?: string;
}

function Home(props: HomeProps) {
  const { date, greeting } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      date: {date}, greeting: {greeting}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a higher order component like this:

```
function GreetingHOC<TOriginalProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<TOriginalProps>,
  props: TOriginalProps
) {

  const injectedProp = 'hello';

  return <Component greeting={injectedProp} {...props} />
}
```

With usage such as this:

```
const compProps = {
  date: +new Date(),
};

GreetingHOC<HomeProps>(Home, compProps);
```

As you can see I have to specify the types of `compProps` by using `<HomeProps>` notation in the in the GreetingHOC() call. Is there a way to type something, so that GreetingHOC checks the actual component being passed in for the required props, something like this:

```
export function GreetingHOC(
  Component: React.Component,
  props: typeof Component.props <-----
) {
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve, you want to be able to define the type of the `props` parameter in the `GreetingHOC` hoc without using generics? And I am not sure why you have to specify the `<HomeProps>` as the generic parameter. Because the `props` param gets inferred successfully without specifying a generic param in `GreetingHOC`: [here's the proof](https://i.ibb.co/tCd79Dz/image.png)

Comment: Yeah, `TOriginalProps` should be inferred for you...